# ScrollView is keeping scrolling although the layout is empty

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is that the ScrollView scrolls till it completes all the content of my layout, then it keeps scrolling and shows empty layout. It keeps scrolling for a long empty length. I guess the problem is in using the RecyclerView inside a ScrollView, and I just know that this will result in a poor UI experience, but the point now is to make it work

Here is the component tree of my layout

[image: the component tree of the layout]

And here is the snippet of the xml code for the part of the ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white_smoke"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout...>
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/comments_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white_smoke" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few solutions. Wrapping the RecyclerView in a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout has solved the problem for me. A final thing to not forget, do not use RecyclerView in a ScrollView as the RecyclerView will not recycle its views. You can do that if you are sure that there are no many items in the RecyclerView.